# How to get a list from a sequential bit pattern using two counters?

Tags: python, string, list, plot

suppose I do have a bit string as an input which I need to plot in a graph. I do have two counters which will append the values of both x-axis and y-axis in a list. Whenever I do have 1 it will be a upwards to downwards (1 to -1) line and whenever I do have 0 it will be a downwards to upward line (-1 to 1).

So, if I do have a bit string of 1011. So the x-axis and y-axis list should be:

```
x= [0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 4]
y= [1, 0.5,-0.5,-1,-1.5, 1.5, 2, 2.5,-2.5,-3, 3, 3.5,-3.5, 4 ]
```

Comment: Your output doesn't really make sense, please double check it and break down the numbers computation

Comment: it's actually correct in a sense. It's for a waveform encoding called manchester!

Comment: Have you tried plotting it? There are lines all over the place. According to your descriptions I would expect only 4 segments, two of which form a single continuous segment

Comment: See [the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV32u.png), it's really unclear how this would derive from `1011`.

Comment: It's entirely unclear how your bit string `1011` relates to the list of coordinates you've provided - stating that it's supposed to be a manchester encoding doesn't help (and seems to be incorrect). Please clarify why the output matches your input - and what have you tried yourself to process and plot this data?

Comment: I might be doing it in a completely wrong way. But is there any possible way to plot manchester encoding based on a bit string?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to perform [Manchester encoding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code):

```
def manchester(bitstr):
    up = [0.5,0.5,-0.5,-0.5]
    down = [-0.5,-0.5,0.5,0.5]
    x = []
    y = []
    for i, b in enumerate(bitstr):
        x.extend([i, i+0.5, i+0.5, i+1])
        y.extend(up if b == '1' else down)
    return x, y

x, y = manchester('1011')
# x: [0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 4]
# y: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y)

# in one shot
# plt.plot(*manchester('1011'))
```

Output:

[image: Manchester wave]

Comment: Have you ever given it a try?